# Can you update metadata with gcloud-node

Tags: node.js, google-cloud-storage, gcloud-node

I'm using [gcloud-node](https://github.com/GoogleCloudPlatform/gcloud-node) to store files on Google Cloud Storage. I would like to update metadata, like the timestamp ala `touch`. Is that possible?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You can pass the metadata to `bucket.write` as in:

```
data = {
  data: 'Hello World',
  metadata: {
    // ...
  }
};
bucket.write('HelloMessageFile', data, function(err, fileObject) {});
```

If you want to update the metadata for an existing file, just pass the metadata inside `data`:

```
data = {
  metadata: {
    // ...
  }
};
bucket.write('HelloMessageFile', data, function(err, fileObject) {});
```